# What does neural network learn? function, parameter or distribution?

Tags: neural-networks

I've learned that a neural network provides a great function approximation. But in some books, it's said that a neural network outputs a "parameter", for example, mean when Gaussian distribution is assumed.

I'm confused with these two facts since in the first view a neural network is just a big function while the second view says that it just provides a parameter, which is a fixed value.

How can I harmonize these two ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probability density function is also a function. Usually a neural network 'acts' as a parametric function $g_\theta(.)$ and the process of training is selecting the $\theta$ based on some notion of optimality. If, say for example, you choose to model things as $g_\theta: \mathbb R^N \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ you might be using the first entry of the output as the mean of a distribution and the second as the log of the variance. Your optimisation criterion would then be something, e.g. like maximizing log likelihood.